# ASP Project, workingn the server: Rebuild or clear application cache

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm working on a .Net/ASP project and my responsibility is to work on the design part of the application only (mostly changing css, js, images, and cshtml files)

I'm working directly on the server, so my app is not running in visual studio or locally or any environment where I can rebuild the app.

That being said, any changes I make to the website takes about 45 minutes before it shows up (I do clear browser cache every time as well).

Is there any way I can manually clear the application cache or rebuild it on the server so my changes start showing immediately?

This is something I added to the we.config but still not helping:

```
<caching>
    <outputCacheSettings enableOutputCache="false"/>
</caching>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm not mistaken the cache you're targetting is not about this kind of resources as they're simply not processed by .NET. This outputcache is rather about the final HTML rendered. So I don't think that's where you should be looking. But there may be some kind of proxy somewhere caching those resources aswell. 
To avoid client/server caching problems with CSS and javascript, I usually add a time ticker to every request avoiding them to be cached client-side. It should also override any "server caching" of those resources, and I would advise testing it manually before putting an automatic solution in place. so, if you're including js file that way :

```
<script src="/mypath/myscript.js"></script>
```

you could just do that :

```
<script src="/mypath/myscript.js?123></script>
```

and see if you get the changes in the file immediately now. If yes, just automate the addition of that number (ideally a timestamp so it's always different on each request) to every javascript/css inclusion you make...

Comment: The css changes are actually happening faster, the changes I make to cshtml files are the ones that take much longer.

Comment: mmmmh... are you sure there isn't some kind of 3rd party or in-hous cache mechanic behind this ? I must admit I'm no expert on caching, but I know this usually doesn't come "out of the box". Could it be that other people of the team have implemented something like this ? It is also important to note that most of the time info from the global web.config can be overrided either by another web.config in a subfolder or even in the codebehind of a specific page or master page.